# publishing to logstash udp in docker

Tags: docker, udp, docker-compose, elastic-stack

I have been strugling with this for a while and I haven't been able to make it work, I'm using docker elk images to start elk in a container, I'm passing the configuration values to elk and I see it working inside the container but the messages don't get to them. This is the configuration I'm using:

```
version: '3'
services:
  elk:
    image: sebp/elk
    ports:
    - '9200:9200'
    - '9300:9300'
    - '5601:5601'
    - '4560:4560'
    - '4560:4560/udp'
    - '9600:9600'
    volumes:
    - './logstashconfig/logstash.conf:/etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf'
```

and this is the configuration file:

```
input {
 udp {
   port => 4560
   codec => plain {
     charset => "UTF-8"
   }
   type => "log4net"
 }
}
```

I can see the logs that its working:

```
UDP listener started {:address=>"0.0.0.0:4560", :receive_buffer_bytes=>"106496", :queue_size=>"2000"}
```

but when I publish logs to that port they don't arrive, I tested my C# console program with an udp listener and the logs are being published, any way this is the configuration I'm using for log4net:

```
<appender name="UdpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.UdpAppender">
  <localPort value="4560" />
  <remoteAddress value="192.168.1.93" />
  <remotePort value="4560" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout, log4net">
    <conversionPattern value="%-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

I also tried the individual images with this other docker-compose.yml but no luck:

```
version: '3'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch
    ports:
    - '9200:9200'
    - '9300:9300'
    command:
    - -Ehttp.cors.enabled=true
    - -Ehttp.cors.allow-origin=*
    - -Ehttp.cors.allow-methods=POST
    - -Ehttp.cors.allow-headers=Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type
  logstash:
    image: logstash
    ports:
    - '4560:4560'
    - '4560:4560/udp'
    - '9600:9600'
    command:
#    - -f logstashconfig/logstash.conf    
    - -e
    - 'input { udp { port => 4560 type => "log4net" } } output { elasticsearch { hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"] } }'
    links:
    - elasticsearch
  kibana:
    image: kibana
    ports:
    - '5601:5601'
    links:
    - elasticsearch
```

I think somehow I'm not exposing the port right but I haven't been able to find the problem, I'm running docker on windows 10.

Comment: What machine is `192.168.1.93` - Are you running this all on one machine or is one of these remote?

Comment: Thats my local ip I'm running all in one machine

Comment: And how are you running this C# app; this is on your local and outside of a Docker container? Try switching to `localhost` instead.

Comment: I'm running it locally, I changed it to localhost and same thing logs don't arrive.

Comment: but I think you´re right it maybe something with the appender, I did a test with Portqry and I got a couple hits to elastic

Comment: Its working now thanks the error was setting the <localPort value="4560" /> in the appender, logs haven't made it to kibana but I can see them in elastic now.

Comment: To add them into Kibana you'll have to add an index pattern. Cheers!

Comment: I added the output configuration to logstash and everything worked great, Thank you!!!